# how to stop state from returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
  const [user,setuser] = useState()

 
  useEffect(()=> {
    try{
    

     const User = (jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem("token")))
     setuser(User)
     console.log(User)
  
      
 
      
      
      
    }catch(e){

    }
  },[])
   
   
   

 console.log(user)

console :undefined
VM7512:249 undefined
App.js:27 {username: 'john4', password: '####', iat: 1649430959}
App.js:42 {username: 'john4', password: '####', iat: 1649430959}
VM7512:249 [object Object]
```

why does the user Object give undefined first is there a way i cant prevent this?
i need the console to only log the actual value and not undefined.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> const [user,setuser] = useState()
> ```

The default value for the state is determine by the argument you pass to `useState`. You aren't passing anything so it is implicitly `undefined`.

Pass it a value.

```
const [user,setuser] = useState("not undefined");
```

---

That said, you probably only want to deal with it after the `useEffect` hook has run. In which case you should generally handle the undefined state explicitly.

A typical example would be:

```
const [user,setuser] = useState()

useEffect(.....);

if (!user) {
    return <LoadingSpinner />
}

return <UserDetails user={user} />
```

---

And that said, your effect hook is running only once (when the component is mounted) and isn't asynchronous, so you could move the logic for it to a function you pass to `useState`.

That function will only run if the state hasn't been set yet, so you still get the benefit of not rerunning it on every render:

```
const [user, setuser] = useState(() => {
    try {
        const User = (jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem("token")))
        setuser(User)
        console.log(User)
    } catch (e) {

    }
});
```